# Spring Boot - POST Request Method did not work but GET did

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot now and I wrote a small application. The application has this controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/account", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
   public String getAccountVo(ModelMap model) {
       AccountVO vo = new AccountVO();
       vo.setAccountNo("0102356");
       vo.setAccountHolderName("Dinesh");

       model.addAttribute("acc", vo);

       return "account";
   }
}
```

... and the page (view) is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Account Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Account number <input type="text" name="acctNo" value="${acc.getAccountNo()}"><br>
        Account Holder Name <input type="text" name="name" value="${acc.getAccountHolderName()}"><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I ran the application, I got `HTTP Status 405` with the message `Request method 'GET' not supported`. But when I changed the method in the `@RequestMapping` annotation to `method=RequestMethod.GET` I got my expected page.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

This means that `getAccountVo` method handler is responsible for `POST` requests on the `/account` endpoint. So when you fire a `GET` request to `/account` endpoint, since you haven't define any method handler to process that, Spring complains with `405 Method Not Supported`.

If your intent is to have a form processing workflow, a typical approach is define two method handlers on the `/account` endpoint: One for displaying the form and other for processing the submitted form, kinda like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/account", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
   public String displayAccountForm(...) {
       // do whatever suits your requirements

       return "account";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value="/account", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
   public String handleSubmittedForm(...) {
       // do whatever suits your requirements

       return "successPage";
   }
}
```